# Write a program that reads N and then continuously read integers and check if there are odd or even until odd and even number equals N

Tags: c#

This is what I tried:

```
using System;

namespace OddAndEvenNumbers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int requiredOddAndEvenNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int oddNumbersCount = 0;
            int evenNumbersCount = 0;
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            while (oddNumbersCount <= requiredOddAndEvenNumbers || evenNumbersCount <= requiredOddAndEvenNumbers)
            {
                if (n % 2 == 0)
                {
                    evenNumbersCount++;
                }
                else if (n % 2 != 0)
                {
                    oddNumbersCount++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(evenNumbersCount + " " + oddNumbersCount);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work.
The program should stop when odd numbers and even number equals N.

Comment: "_I don't know why it doesn't work_" That's what a debugger is for: To learn how some code actually behaves and why it behaves as it does. A debugger allows you to _observe_ what your code is doing, its actual behavior and the things it does you did not intend it to do. Armed with these insights, you can then fix the problem. Introduction to debugging with Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger

Comment: Even without using the debugger you should have noticed that your code asks for input just one time after asking for N and then dies...

Answer (score 0):

You never update `n` so the loop will never exit
So `evenNumbersCount` and `oddNumbersCount` will never count up

```
using System;

namespace OddAndEvenNumbers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int requiredOddAndEvenNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int oddNumbersCount = 0;
            int evenNumbersCount = 0;
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            while (oddNumbersCount <= requiredOddAndEvenNumbers || evenNumbersCount <= requiredOddAndEvenNumbers)
            {
                if (n % 2 == 0)
                {
                    evenNumbersCount++;
                }
                else if (n % 2 != 0)
                {
                    oddNumbersCount++;
                }
                n++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(evenNumbersCount + " " + oddNumbersCount);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "_So evenNumbersCount and oddNumbersCount will never count up_". How could this be possible with the code given in the question? (Assuming the input is valid and Convert.ToInt32 doesn't throw.) For this to be possible, the initial value of `n` would need to be both not even and not odd, which, considering n is an int, is not really possible. One of evenNumbersCount or oddNumbersCount _will_ count up.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace this is why i added the `n++` that is not in the question

Comment: That doesn't change anything about what i said. "_So evenNumbersCount and oddNumbersCount will never count up_" is just a false/erroneous statement, regardless of whether you added `n++` to the code or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've forgotten to get new number inside the loop. It keeps checking the first number
ItThe while loop works until the `Odd + Even numbers are equal to n`.

```
int requiredOddAndEvenNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int oddNumbersCount = 0;
int evenNumbersCount = 0;
int n = 0;

while ((oddNumbersCount + evenNumbersCount) < requiredOddAndEvenNumbers)
{
    n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        evenNumbersCount++;
    }
    else if (n % 2 != 0)
    {
        oddNumbersCount++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("evenNumbersCount: {0}", evenNumbersCount);
Console.WriteLine("oddNumbersCount: {0}", oddNumbersCount);
```